# Стили СSS для элементов asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#, html, asp.net-webforms, css

Asp.net позволяет добавлять на странички различные сложные элементы наподобие gridview и т.д., которые при открытии страницы трансформируются в набор HTML тегов.

**Как для таких элементов (как gridview) писать стили в CSS? Нужно открывать код этого элемента и на основе него писать селекторы СSS? Или на это нельзя полагаться и в разных браузерах gridview может разворачиваться в разные наборы тегов HTML? Как принято поступать в таких случаях в asp.net?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает явно указать вашим элементам css-класс?

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="class_name" />
```

GridView в ASP.NET рендерится в HTML-таблицу в любом браузере. Соответственно, и в стиле указываете селекторы для таблицы.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо. Просто хотел убедится, что так действительно можно делать, т.е. то, что не возникнет ситуации, когда один и тот же элемент asp.net будет рендерится в разные наборы HTML элементов в разных браузерах.

Answer (score 1):

Вот живой пример:

```
    /*GridView 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.GridViewSt { font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: small; table-layout: auto; border-collapse: collapse; }
.PagerSt table { text-align: center; margin: auto; }
.PagerSt table td { border: 0px; padding: 5px; }
.PagerSt td { border-top: #fff 1px solid; }
.PagerSt a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; border-top: solid 1px #fff; border-right: solid 1px #91a7b4; border-bottom: solid 1px #91a7b4; border-left: solid 1px #fff; background-color: #FFE4B5; }
.PagerSt span { font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px; border-top: solid 1px #91a7b4; border-right: solid 1px #fff; border-bottom: solid 1px #fff; border-left: solid 1px #91a7b4; background-color: #fff; }

<asp:GridView
                        ID="gvCoffee"
                        runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"

                        AllowPaging="True"
                        PageIndex="0"
                        CellPadding="10"
                        ShowHeader="False"
                        PageSize="4"

                        CssClass="GridViewCoffee"
                        PagerStyle-CssClass="PagerCoffee">
```